# IE6 PNG transparency fix with Background positioned

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, png-transparency

I am using this to fix PNG transparency on background images in IE6

```
ul li a
{
    background-image: url('/NewSite/Content/Images/Sprite.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -48px;
    background-image: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=/NewSite/Content/Images/Sprite.png, sizingMethod='crop');
}
```

This works great, however I have run into a problem when trying to implement this with a sprite. The fix ignores the positioning and renders as if the position was top right.

Is there a way to force background position or a better way to do this. I would prefer to not use JavaScript or change to gifs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to do what you want is with [IEPNGFix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/)
You will have to use JavaScript, but you can warp it under conditional comments, like i do.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie6.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iepngfix_tilebg.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Inside ie6.css

```
ul li a { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc); }
```

Comment: This is my accepted answer, but I had to be able to execute without JavaScript. I ended up just dropping the sprite and using my method with individual images. However, it worked great so that's for the tip.